# Python recursion name not defined

Tags: python, recursion

So I am making a script that looks like this,

```
wanttodoagain()
def wanttodoagain()
    print ("Hi whats your name?")
    name = input ('')
    print ("Hi, {}".format(name))
    print ("So, do you want to do this again?????")
    print ("Y/N, it has to be capital")
    doagainanswer=input("")
    if doagainanswer=="Y":
        wanttodoagain()
    if doagainanswer=="N":
        print ("OK, bye")
```

I want the recursion to start automatically because when I close it and run it from my desktop it shows a window not the python shell that closes automatically and does not wait for the user to enter "wanttodoagain()".
When I run it in python shell, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jason Nguyen/Desktop/askname.py", line 1, in <module>
    wanttodoagain()
NameError: name 'wanttodoagain()' is not defined
```

Comment: Put the first line at the end. Functions must be defined before you call them in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the call *after* defining the function:

```
def wanttodoagain()
    print ("Hi whats your name?")
    name = input ('')
    print ("Hi, {}".format(name))
    print ("So, do you want to do this again?????")
    print ("Y/N, it has to be capital")
    doagainanswer=input("")
    if doagainanswer=="Y":
        wanttodoagain()
    if doagainanswer=="N":
        print ("OK, bye")

wanttodoagain()
```

Only when the interpreter has executed the `def` compound statement does the name `wanttodoagain` exist.

However, I'd not use recursion to ask for user feedback. Never underestimate the enthusiasm of your users; they only have to hit `Y` 1000 times for your program to hit the recursion limit. Just use a `while True` loop:

```
while True:
    print ("Hi whats your name?")
    name = input ('')
    print ("Hi, {}".format(name))
    print ("So, do you want to do this again?????")
    print ("Y/N, it has to be capital")
    doagainanswer=input("")
    if doagainanswer=="N":
        print ("OK, bye")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first define the function before calling it. Now python interpreter doesn't know what is `wanttodoagain`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `wanttodoagain` function before you define it, just put the first line below function definition:

```
def wanttodoagain()
    print ("Hi whats your name?")
    name = input ('')
    print ("Hi, {}".format(name))
    print ("So, do you want to do this again?????")
    print ("Y/N, it has to be capital")
    doagainanswer=input("")
    if doagainanswer=="Y":
        wanttodoagain()
    if doagainanswer=="N":
        print ("OK, bye")


wanttodoagain()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call should be after the function is defined. You can also put the prompts for user input inside your input call. This should work for you:

```
def wanttodoagain():
    name = input("Hi whats your name?")
    print ("Hi, {}".format(name))
    print ("So, do you want to do this again?????")
    doagainanswer = input("Y/N, it has to be capital")
    if doagainanswer == "Y":
        wanttodoagain()
    if doagainanswer == "N":
        print ("OK, bye")
wanttodoagain()
```

Comment: I cant add and answer because everyone's answers are correct. Thank you for all your help!!!!! @Heinst Nearly everyone's answer's are mostly the same, so I don't know what to chose as the correct answer.

Comment: @PhichNguyen then accept the one you think is the best answer